# Multi-line code in PHP interactive shell

Tags: php, shell, command-line, syntax

I'm learning to use the PHP interactive shell, but I'm having trouble with multi-line code.

Using backslashes like in the UNIX shells doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong ?

```
php > function test(){\
php { echo "test";\
php { }\
php > test();
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO, expecting T_STRING in php shell code on line 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't escape it:

```
php > function test()
php > {
php {   echo "test";
php { }
php > test();
test
```

However, you will have problems in certain cases, such as:

```
php > if(conditional)
php > {
php {   // ...
php { }
php > else
php > {
php {   // ...
php { }
```

It thinks the if is over before it sees the else, so you get a "unexpected T_ELSE".  In this case, there's a work-around:

```
php > if(conditional)
php > {
php {   // ...
php { } else
php > {
php {   // ...
php { }
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional info !